# After POSTing the form and implementing form_valid() method I get "object has no user" error

Tags: python, django

Good evening. I'm trying to add a blog to the subscription list of a user which is currently logged in. I'm expecting that after I submit a subscription form the values of "user" and "blogs_in_subscription" (it will be taken from a current url from "blog_pk" kwarg) of SubscriptionList model will be automatically populated by the values that I get from form_valid method of my AddBlogToSubList view. But I get this error:

```
File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\src\blog\models.py" in __str__
  42.       return "%s subscription list" % self.user.username
File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  194.                 "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /blogs/1/add_to_subscription/
Exception Value: SubscriptionList has no user.
```

The same method works in django official documentation

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    return super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work in my case. Any help appreciated.

models

```
class SubscriptionList(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='subscription_list')
blogs_in_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(Blog, related_name='in_subscription_lists',
                                                blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s subscription list" % self.user.username
```

views

```
class AddBlogToSubList(CreateView):
model = SubscriptionList
fields = [] #['user', 'blogs_in_subscription']
template_name = 'blog/add_blog_to_sub_list.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:blog-list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['blog_pk'])
    form.instance.blogs_in_subscription.add(blog)
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(AddBlogToSubList, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', BlogList.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/$', BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/add_to_subscription/$', AddBlogToSubList.as_view(), name='add-to-subscription'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/subscriptions/$', SubscriptionListView.as_view(), name='subscription-list'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/create/$', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post-create'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/$', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/update/$', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post-update'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
```

]

Comment: I think your problem is on this line`fields = [] #['user', 'blogs_in_subscription']` you should use your commented line or `fields = '__all__'`

Comment: I've just commented out 'user' and 'blogs_in_subscription' to emphasize that the form is empty. It should be filled out by values from form_valid().

Comment: Check if the the user object specified exists or not as well as the blog referenced by the id in url also exists or not.That's what I think from the error.

Comment: @nitangle The user object exists and works perfectly fine with other views and templates. The current view is triggered when I get to url:
' url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/add_to_subscription/$', AddBlogToSubList.as_view(), name='add-to-subscription')'
at this point the blog id is mentioned in 'blog_pk' kwarg